# Dot product with sparse matrix and vector

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix, vector

Im having a very hard time trying to program a dot product with a matrix in sparse format and a vector.

My matrix have the shape 3 x 3 in the folowing format:

```
Ms=[[0, 0, 0.6153414193508929],[1, 1, 0.9884632853575251],[2, 1, 0.22943483758936845],[2, 2, 0.336180557968783]]
```

Where the first index represent the row number, the second is the column number and third is the data. 
the vector "b" is:

```
b=Array([[0.32599637],[0.31726302],[0.67265016]])
```

My question is: how i format the FOR-loop to iterate the third index in Ms (Ie: Column 0) and add the multiplication of the columns with the consequent index in "b", and jump to the next row. (like the description of dot product)

Please, if you don´t undestand ask me to clarify

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: the Ms is a list, and the b vector is an array.

Comment: "add the multiplication of the columns with the consequent index in 'b'". What does this mean? What is the expected output?

Comment: i was trying to define the dot product between a matrix and a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that if `A` is a matrix of shape `(M, N)`, and `b` is a vector of shape `(N, 1)`, then `A.b` equals a vector `c` of shape `(M, 1)`.

A row `x_c` in `c` = `sum((x_A, a row in A) * b)`.

```
def dot(sparse_mat, dense_vec, sparse_shape):
    assert sparse_shape[1] == dense_vec.shape[0], "Columns of matrix must be equal to rows of vector."
    
    output = np.zeros((sparse_shape[0], dense_vec.shape[1]))
    
    for (row, col, val) in sparse_mat:
        row, col = int(row), int(col)
        output[row] += dense_vec[int(col)] * val
    
    return output


Ms = [[0, 0, 0.6153414193508929],
      [1, 1, 0.9884632853575251],
      [2, 1, 0.22943483758936845],
      [2, 2, 0.336180557968783]]

b = np.array([[0.32599637],
              [0.31726302],
              [0.67265016]])

print(dot(Ms, b, (3, 3)))

# [[0.20059907]
#  [0.31360285]
#  [0.2989231 ]]
```

We should verify the above with scipy's sparse matrices.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
Ms = np.array(Ms)
sparse_M = csr_matrix((Ms[:, 2], (Ms[:, 0].astype(int), Ms[:, 1].astype(int))), (3, 3))
print(sparse_M)

#  (0, 0)   0.6153414193508929
#  (1, 1)   0.9884632853575251
#  (2, 1)   0.22943483758936845
#  (2, 2)   0.336180557968783

print(sparse_M @ b)

# [[0.20059907]
#  [0.31360285]
#  [0.2989231 ]]
```

Comment: wow! this code works fine! Thanks a lot!!